# installfest rake db:migrate the system cannot find the path specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am going through the installfest process to get started with Ruby on Rails for the odin project, but I'm falling short at the final stage. I've installed everything they asked exactly as instructed, but when I run 'rake db:migrate' i get the message 'The system cannot find the path specified.'
I cant find anything for this on the internet, the solutions I've found all say the target file has the wrong code but when I correct as advised I still get the same message.

I am doing this for a windows system.

```
C:\Users\Olaoluwa>rails -v
Rails 5.0.2

C:\Users\Olaoluwa>cd c:\Sites

c:\Sites>mkdir railsbridge
A subdirectory or file railsbridge already exists.

c:\Sites>cd railsbridge

c:\Sites\railsbridge>cd test_app

c:\Sites\railsbridge\test_app>rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.2 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
*** SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGUSR1 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGHUP not implemented, signal based logs reopening unavailable!
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.7.1 (ruby 2.3.3-p222), codename: Snowy Sagebrush
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
Exiting
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y

c:\Sites\railsbridge\test_app>rake db:migrate
The system cannot find the path specified.

c:\Sites\railsbridge\test_app>

Edit: 
my gemfile.lock shows
GEM
remote: https://rubygems.org/
specs:
codeclimate-test-reporter (0.3.0)
  simplecov (>= 0.7.1, < 1.0.0)
diff-lcs (1.2.3)
docile (1.1.3)
multi_json (1.9.0)
rack (1.5.2)
rack-protection (1.5.0)
  rack
rake (10.0.4)
rspec (2.13.0)
  rspec-core (~> 2.13.0)
  rspec-expectations (~> 2.13.0)
  rspec-mocks (~> 2.13.0)
rspec-core (2.13.1)
rspec-expectations (2.13.0)
  diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3, < 2.0)
rspec-mocks (2.13.1)
simplecov (0.8.2)
  docile (~> 1.1.0)
  multi_json
  simplecov-html (~> 0.8.0)
simplecov-html (0.8.0)
sinatra (1.4.2)
  rack (~> 1.5, >= 1.5.2)
  rack-protection (~> 1.4)
  tilt (~> 1.3, >= 1.3.4)
tilt (1.3.7)

PLATFORMS
java
ruby

DEPENDENCIES
codeclimate-test-reporter
rack
rake
rspec
sinatra
```

Comment: Edit: in case you were wondering what is in the batch file

     @ECHO OFF
     IF NOT "%~f0" == "~f0" GOTO :WinNT
     @"%~dp0ruby.exe"
     "C:/Users/emachnic/GitRepos/railsinstaller-windows/stage/Ruby2.2.0/bin/rails" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
     GOTO :EOF
     :WinNT
     @"%~dp0ruby.exe" "%~dpn0" %*

Comment: can you post your Gemfile.lock?

Comment: @eiko i searched my files for gemfile.lock and opened th first one with sublime text, this is what came up

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't figured this out yet, it looks like running rails db:migrate should be the way it's done in Rails5 instead of rake db:migrate.

This is based off of this thread:
https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/60gjx3/help_when_using_rake_dbmigrate_i_get_return_error/

Comment: I was actually able to solve it by simply using the Ubuntu Linux OS on a virtual machine instead of windows, cheers for the help. Forgot to update here. Not sure how to close the question

Answer (score 0):

If anyone faces the same problem?! This just because the db folder does not has the development sqlite3 file : ***development.sqlite3*** To solve it, go to your app root directory (i.e: Blog, Todo [YOUR APP FOLDER]) then run this command on terminal : `rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development`

Answer (score -1):

The error is simply showing `rake db:migrate` is not working.

install latest rake gem:-

`gem 'rake', '~> 11.2', '>= 11.2.2'`
`gem install rake -v 11.2.2`

and restart the server: `rails s`